# Hough circle detection accuracy very low

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, edge-detection

I am trying to detect a circular shape from an image which appears to have very good definition. I do realize that part of the circle is missing but from what I've read about the Hough transform it doesn't seem like that should cause the problem I'm experiencing.

Input:
[image: Output image]

Output:
[image]

Code:

```
// Read the image
Mat src = Highgui.imread("input.png");

// Convert it to gray
Mat src_gray = new Mat();
Imgproc.cvtColor(src, src_gray, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

// Reduce the noise so we avoid false circle detection
//Imgproc.GaussianBlur( src_gray, src_gray, new Size(9, 9), 2, 2 );

Mat circles = new Mat();

/// Apply the Hough Transform to find the circles
Imgproc.HoughCircles(src_gray, circles, Imgproc.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 1, 160, 25, 0, 0);

// Draw the circles detected
for( int i = 0; i < circles.cols(); i++ ) {
    double[] vCircle = circles.get(0, i);

    Point center = new Point(vCircle[0], vCircle[1]);
    int radius = (int) Math.round(vCircle[2]);

    // circle center
    Core.circle(src, center, 3, new Scalar(0, 255, 0), -1, 8, 0);
    // circle outline
    Core.circle(src, center, radius, new Scalar(0, 0, 255), 3, 8, 0);
}

// Save the visualized detection.
String filename = "output.png";
System.out.println(String.format("Writing %s", filename));
Highgui.imwrite(filename, src);
```

I have Gaussian blur commented out because (counter intuitively) it was greatly increasing the number of equally inaccurate circles found.

Is there anything wrong with my input image that would cause Hough to not work as well as I expect? Are my parameters way off?

EDIT: first answer brought up a good point about the min/max radius hint for Hough. I resisted adding those parameters as the example image in this post is just one of thousands of images all with varying radii from ~20 to almost infinity.

Comment: I think the problem is, that `Imgproc.HoughCircles` internally uses a gradient filter and doesnt assume line data input. So after gradient computation, some of your lines might vanish or be doubled.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense now that I think about it! I had assumed that giving it simple white lines on a black background would be ideal but I see now that it may not be. Is there a way to tell OpenCV that I don't want HoughCircles() to preprocess the input? I'm going to try now with the raw images before the Canny processing and see if there is a marked difference.

Comment: In theory openCV has different methods instead of CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, but according to the documentation they're not implemented yet. I've played a little with filling the circles (in GIMP) but didnt get good results either. Maybe your circles aren't perfect enough or something. I've implemented a semi-circle detection with RANSAC in the past, I could try to adjust that for your task, but can't promise anything at the moment (and it would be in c++).

Comment: I was getting these very poor results too.  The trouble is I was leaving the HoughCircles accumulator array resolution, aka (dp setting) to the default `1`, as you did.  Increase to 1.7 and I was delighted by the stunning sub-pixel perfect accuracy.  Still, HoughCircles is a bit finicky and a few stray aliased pixels can send the tangent via the edge gradient (and thus the votes) off in the wrong direction, resulting in circles being found as much as half a radii away. If you don't know your radius before you begin then you'll have to deal with incorrectly placed circles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd set `minRadius` and `maxRadius` paramaeters properly, it'd give you good results.

For your image, I tried following parameters.

```
method - CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT
minDist - 100
dp - 1
param1 - 80
param2 - 10
minRadius - 250
maxRadius - 300
```

I got the following output

[image]

- Note: I tried this in C++.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I probably should have mentioned the min and max radius in the OP but the image I posted is just one example of thousands of images all with varying radii from ~20 to ~500. Also, the fit in your result, while certainly better than mine, is still not what I would consider "good." I'm trying to determine the exact angle at the intersection of the two circles so the error on the left of the bottom circle would pose quite a problem. Thanks again for your contribution!

Comment: Hough isn't that perfect and min max radius are important parameters. I'd just leave this link here. I recently used this for detecting around 200 circles in an image. It was highly accurate. http://ceng.anadolu.edu.tr/CV/EDCircles/demo.aspx The link seems unavailable as of now. I used it last week only. See if it works. it's a good solution. `EDCircles`

Answer (score 6):

I've adjusted my RANSAC algorithm from this answer: [Detect semi-circle in opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20698613/detect-semi-circle-in-opencv/20734263#20734263)

Idea:

1. choose randomly 3 points from your binary edge image
2. create a circle from those 3 points
3. test how "good" this circle is
4. if it is better than the previously best found circle in this image, remember
5. loop 1-4 until some number of iterations reached. then accept the best found circle.
6. remove that accepted circle from the image
7. repeat 1-6 until you have found all circles

problems:

1. at the moment you must know how many circles you want to find in the image
2. tested only for that one image.
3. c++ code

result:

[image]

code:

```
    inline void getCircle(cv::Point2f& p1,cv::Point2f& p2,cv::Point2f& p3, cv::Point2f& center, float& radius)
    {
      float x1 = p1.x;
      float x2 = p2.x;
      float x3 = p3.x;

      float y1 = p1.y;
      float y2 = p2.y;
      float y3 = p3.y;

      // PLEASE CHECK FOR TYPOS IN THE FORMULA :)
      center.x = (x1*x1+y1*y1)*(y2-y3) + (x2*x2+y2*y2)*(y3-y1) + (x3*x3+y3*y3)*(y1-y2);
      center.x /= ( 2*(x1*(y2-y3) - y1*(x2-x3) + x2*y3 - x3*y2) );

      center.y = (x1*x1 + y1*y1)*(x3-x2) + (x2*x2+y2*y2)*(x1-x3) + (x3*x3 + y3*y3)*(x2-x1);
      center.y /= ( 2*(x1*(y2-y3) - y1*(x2-x3) + x2*y3 - x3*y2) );

      radius = sqrt((center.x-x1)*(center.x-x1) + (center.y-y1)*(center.y-y1));
    }



    std::vector<cv::Point2f> getPointPositions(cv::Mat binaryImage)
    {
     std::vector<cv::Point2f> pointPositions;

     for(unsigned int y=0; y<binaryImage.rows; ++y)
     {
         //unsigned char* rowPtr = binaryImage.ptr<unsigned char>(y);
         for(unsigned int x=0; x<binaryImage.cols; ++x)
         {
             //if(rowPtr[x] > 0) pointPositions.push_back(cv::Point2i(x,y));
             if(binaryImage.at<unsigned char>(y,x) > 0) pointPositions.push_back(cv::Point2f(x,y));
         }
     }

     return pointPositions;
    }


    float verifyCircle(cv::Mat dt, cv::Point2f center, float radius, std::vector<cv::Point2f> & inlierSet)
    {
     unsigned int counter = 0;
     unsigned int inlier = 0;
     float minInlierDist = 2.0f;
     float maxInlierDistMax = 100.0f;
     float maxInlierDist = radius/25.0f;
     if(maxInlierDist<minInlierDist) maxInlierDist = minInlierDist;
     if(maxInlierDist>maxInlierDistMax) maxInlierDist = maxInlierDistMax;

     // choose samples along the circle and count inlier percentage
     for(float t =0; t<2*3.14159265359f; t+= 0.05f)
     {
         counter++;
         float cX = radius*cos(t) + center.x;
         float cY = radius*sin(t) + center.y;

         if(cX < dt.cols)
         if(cX >= 0)
         if(cY < dt.rows)
         if(cY >= 0)
         if(dt.at<float>(cY,cX) < maxInlierDist)
         {
            inlier++;
            inlierSet.push_back(cv::Point2f(cX,cY));
         }
     }

     return (float)inlier/float(counter);
    }

    float evaluateCircle(cv::Mat dt, cv::Point2f center, float radius)
    {

        float completeDistance = 0.0f;
        int counter = 0;

        float maxDist = 1.0f;   //TODO: this might depend on the size of the circle!

        float minStep = 0.001f;
        // choose samples along the circle and count inlier percentage

        //HERE IS THE TRICK that no minimum/maximum circle is used, the number of generated points along the circle depends on the radius.
        // if this is too slow for you (e.g. too many points created for each circle), increase the step parameter, but only by factor so that it still depends on the radius

        // the parameter step depends on the circle size, otherwise small circles will create more inlier on the circle
        float step = 2*3.14159265359f / (6.0f * radius);
        if(step < minStep) step = minStep; // TODO: find a good value here.

        //for(float t =0; t<2*3.14159265359f; t+= 0.05f) // this one which doesnt depend on the radius, is much worse!
        for(float t =0; t<2*3.14159265359f; t+= step)
        {
            float cX = radius*cos(t) + center.x;
            float cY = radius*sin(t) + center.y;

            if(cX < dt.cols)
                if(cX >= 0)
                    if(cY < dt.rows)
                        if(cY >= 0)
                            if(dt.at<float>(cY,cX) <= maxDist)
                            {
                                completeDistance += dt.at<float>(cY,cX);
                                counter++;
                            }

        }

        return counter;
    }


    int main()
    {
    //RANSAC

    cv::Mat color = cv::imread("HoughCirclesAccuracy.png");

    // convert to grayscale
    cv::Mat gray;
    cv::cvtColor(color, gray, CV_RGB2GRAY);

    // get binary image
    cv::Mat mask = gray > 0;

    unsigned int numberOfCirclesToDetect = 2;   // TODO: if unknown, you'll have to find some nice criteria to stop finding more (semi-) circles

    for(unsigned int j=0; j<numberOfCirclesToDetect; ++j)
    {
        std::vector<cv::Point2f> edgePositions;
        edgePositions = getPointPositions(mask);

        std::cout << "number of edge positions: " << edgePositions.size() << std::endl;

        // create distance transform to efficiently evaluate distance to nearest edge
        cv::Mat dt;
        cv::distanceTransform(255-mask, dt,CV_DIST_L1, 3);



        unsigned int nIterations = 0;

        cv::Point2f bestCircleCenter;
        float bestCircleRadius;
        //float bestCVal = FLT_MAX;
        float bestCVal = -1;

        //float minCircleRadius = 20.0f; // TODO: if you have some knowledge about your image you might be able to adjust the minimum circle radius parameter.
        float minCircleRadius = 0.0f;

        //TODO: implement some more intelligent ransac without fixed number of iterations
        for(unsigned int i=0; i<2000; ++i)
        {
            //RANSAC: randomly choose 3 point and create a circle:
            //TODO: choose randomly but more intelligent,
            //so that it is more likely to choose three points of a circle.
            //For example if there are many small circles, it is unlikely to randomly choose 3 points of the same circle.
            unsigned int idx1 = rand()%edgePositions.size();
            unsigned int idx2 = rand()%edgePositions.size();
            unsigned int idx3 = rand()%edgePositions.size();

            // we need 3 different samples:
            if(idx1 == idx2) continue;
            if(idx1 == idx3) continue;
            if(idx3 == idx2) continue;

            // create circle from 3 points:
            cv::Point2f center; float radius;
            getCircle(edgePositions[idx1],edgePositions[idx2],edgePositions[idx3],center,radius);

            if(radius < minCircleRadius)continue;


            //verify or falsify the circle by inlier counting:
            //float cPerc = verifyCircle(dt,center,radius, inlierSet);
            float cVal = evaluateCircle(dt,center,radius);

            if(cVal > bestCVal)
            {
                bestCVal = cVal;
                bestCircleRadius = radius;
                bestCircleCenter = center;
            }

            ++nIterations;
        }
        std::cout << "current best circle: " << bestCircleCenter << " with radius: " << bestCircleRadius << " and nInlier " << bestCVal << std::endl;
        cv::circle(color,bestCircleCenter,bestCircleRadius,cv::Scalar(0,0,255));

        //TODO: hold and save the detected circle.

        //TODO: instead of overwriting the mask with a drawn circle it might be better to hold and ignore detected circles and dont count new circles which are too close to the old one.
        // in this current version the chosen radius to overwrite the mask is fixed and might remove parts of other circles too!

        // update mask: remove the detected circle!
        cv::circle(mask,bestCircleCenter, bestCircleRadius, 0, 10); // here the radius is fixed which isnt so nice.
    }

    cv::namedWindow("edges"); cv::imshow("edges", mask);
    cv::namedWindow("color"); cv::imshow("color", color);

    cv::imwrite("detectedCircles.png", color);
    cv::waitKey(-1);
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Wow! This looks very similar to the method we're currently using. I didn't realize it had a name. Do you know if lots of random noise in the image would influence the results of this method in a negative way?

Comment: With noise some things might change: its harder to get an ok binary edge image. The circle test with distance transform might get false inlier. And you will need more RANSAC iterations than without noise. But true circles should still give better circle tests than noise samples so I guess the method should still work.

Comment: It looks like the RANSAC algorithm is what I was looking for and I'm going to be using a variation of it in my program. However, I'm accepting the other answer since it actually explains why my Hough circle results were lackluster and how to improve them. I really appreciate your input!