# opencv: how to detect semi-circle or semi-oval or semi-ellipse

Tags: opencv, contour

Update:

The approach shown in this post: [Detect semi-circle in opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20698613/detect-semi-circle-in-opencv) does not work in my case.

I appended the results.
[image]
[image]

---

Original:

I am using OpenCV to detect a semi-circle like shape.
My idea is to find contours first and do some analysis later. Then I got stuck here. What are the rules to check whether the contour is a semi-circle shape?

Or maybe I should try matchShapes? Or feature detection which I think is a little overweight for such a task.

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated!

Thanks
Deryk

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect semi-circle in opencv](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20698613/detect-semi-circle-in-opencv)

Comment: It is different. I am detecting a closed semi-circle like shape while that post is detecting a open semi-circle.

Comment: A closed semi-circle is just an open semi-circle plus a line, you can detect both using Hough transforms. Did you try the answers to the duplicate question?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. That approach does not work for my case. I appended the results in my post.

Comment: I suppose those curves are not close enough to circular

Comment: matchShapes does not work well either. I am not familiar with feature detection, like SIFT, SURF. Is that an option?

Comment: As you really only have edges, and SIFT suppresses features near edges, I don't think SIFT (or SURF) will be useful.  You could try shape contexts or chordiograms  http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~malik/papers/mori-belongie-malik-pami05.pdf http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~taskar/pubs/segment_cvpr10.pdf