# Is there any way to "approximate" the rest of a circle in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to detect circles in some pictures but the circles aren't always perfect. This makes `houghCircles` very impractical to use because it seems to only support almost perfect circles. So now i am searching for a way to kind of "fix" my circles.

for reproduction purposes:

First i threshold the picture to get a binary picutre:

```cpp
cv::threshold(input, output, threshvalue, 1, cv::THRESH_BINARY_INV);
```

After thresholding i detect the Hough Circles with :

```cpp
std::vector<cv::Vec3f> circles;
HoughCircles(binarypicture,circles,cv::HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,100,30,26,45);
```

[image: An example of an imperfect circle]

Comment: I think you should show a [mcve] so everyone can see what type of filtering you've used etc. Showing the original picture and the result after applying different filters may also help someone used to OpenCV to spot what needs to be done.

Comment: have a look at RANSAC circle detection: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26222525/opencv-detect-partial-circle-with-noise/26234137#26234137

Comment: Before applying (Hough circle or circle fitting ) filter those blobs or edges and keep just ARCS ... by the way there is a new hough algorithm (HOUGH_GRADIENT_ALT) if you use the latest OpenCV version.