# Ransac for edg detection

Tags: c++, algorithm, opencv, ransac

I am studing Ransac algorithm to make edges detection much more robust to light conditions.
My project:"Mouth state detection". I used face detection and mouth detection (Data in OpenCV) to detect  mouth of person. Then I find mouth's contour to get chaincode, before use chaincode to train with Support Vector Machine. My problem i can not get good mouth's contour. I want to use Ransac algorithm to make edges detection much more robust. Please help me!

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: You need to be much more specific.

Comment: My question: How can I use Ransac algorithm to make edges detection of mouth? I read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20698613/detect-semi-circle-in-opencv. I want to do same that with Mouth! please tell me the way!

Comment: @Happy you typically use RANSAC to find parameters on a model, like the values for a parametric shape (like a circle) or the parameters for a transformation. Do you have a model for the shape of a mouth?

Comment: In RANSAC you typically can create a model from a small number of samples and accept or deny this model after a test. Dont see how to do this for edges (instead of lines)

Comment: @PeterT: I have just only to detect mouth and find contour to get chaincode. I am new member to research OpenCV. Could you explain cleanly to make model for shape of a mouth? thank you!

Comment: @Micka Iread yuo have writen"Here is another way to do it, a simple RANSAC version (much optimization to be done to improve speed), that works on the Edge Image" I want to find contour of mouth, then get chaincode of contour. So i want to use RANSAC algorithm to make edges detection much more robust to light conditions. Could you show me the way? than you!

Comment: @Happy that's because his model was a simple parametric circle, a mouth is not such a simple geometric shape. RANSAC does not do arbitrary edge-detecting, you are misunderstanding what is being done there.

Comment: @happy if your mouth has a (quite) fixed shape there might be a way to use RANSAC. But maybe you want to test other methods like "active contour" instead.

Comment: @Happy RANSAC is not an edge detection algorithm. It is designed for robust parameter estimation. In Computer vision, usually edge or corners' position are given as the input of RANSAC.