# Center of mass of irregular point distribution

Tags: c++, opencv

I have an image of points which "visually" form a closed circle. However, the points are unequally distributed along this "contour", which results in the center of mass being skewed. I tried using `findContours` but that doesn't find a closed line.

Is there a simple solution?

Edit: 
The points are stored in vectors for x and corresponding y-coordinates, I plotted them using `cv::circle`.

Image: white + red = whole vectors (720 points), red = first half of vector (360 points)

[image]

Original image:

[image]

Comment: sounds more like a `smallest enclosing ball` problem

Comment: probably `convexHull` and `minEnclosingCircle` will help here. Post an image and some relevant code.

Comment: Add the original image too (no red dots), so I can provide a working example.

Comment: feel free to try my answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27095483/improving-circle-detection/27100805#27100805 which uses a simple RANSAC to find circles.If you instead want to use `minEnclosingCircle` be aware that it really will find the ENCLOSING circle, so if you irregular distributed points are really bad on a single side, you might get a bad result, too.

Comment: ok... I think I misunderstood your problem. You don't necessarily want to find the "circle" but instead the center of gravity? But you can't compute CoG mathematically because there are more "point samples per inch" in some part of your data? Maybe you can just count the points in some kind of macro-cells and remove single points from some cells until all macro-blocks have same point count?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [minEnclosingCircle](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#minenclosingcircle) to find the smallest circle containing all your points.

You get the `center` as output value of the function:

```
void minEnclosingCircle(InputArray points, Point2f& center, float& radius)
```

---

**UPDATE**

I tried a few different things. **I assumed that you know that your final shape would be a circle**.

- `minEnclosingCircle`
- `boundingRect`
- `fitEllipse`

The best result (in this image) seems to be with `fitEllipse`.

**Results**

minEnclosingCircle:

[image]

boundingRect:

[image]

fitEllipse:

[image]

Code:

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    Mat1b img = imread("path_to_image", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

    vector<Point> points;
    findNonZero(img, points);

    Mat3b res;
    cvtColor(img, res, CV_GRAY2BGR);

    //////////////////////////////////
    // Method 1: minEnclosingCircle
    //////////////////////////////////

    /*Point2f center;
    float radius;
    minEnclosingCircle(points, center, radius);

    circle(res, center, radius, Scalar(255,0,0), 1);
    circle(res, center, 5, Scalar(0,255,0), 1);*/


    //////////////////////////////////
    // Method 2: boundingRect
    //////////////////////////////////

    /*Rect bbox = boundingRect(points);

    rectangle(res, bbox, Scalar(0,255,255));
    circle(res, Point(bbox.x + bbox.width/2, bbox.y + bbox.height/2), 5, Scalar(0,0,255));*/


    //////////////////////////////////
    // Method 3: fit ellipse
    //////////////////////////////////

    RotatedRect ell = fitEllipse(points);
    ellipse(res, ell, Scalar(255,255,0));
    circle(res, ell.center, 5, Scalar(255,0,255));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think this might work. Let me try it for a few test images.