# How to detect shapes and area on an image

Tags: javascript, python, opencv, web

I am currently working on something like kik/messenger code, just for fun.

At this point, I create the code with Javascript in Canvas. The result is the following :

[image: This is the result for the code]

So my question is the following one :
How can I detect shapes and area of shapes? Specially area. I saw articles about some solution in Python with OpenCV but I'm not sure about how to implement them :/.

**[BONUS]** : If you can tell shapes location you'll have my entire respect and admiration! Something like this :
[image: Number]

Thank you a lot!

Comment: Could you give us a link to the articles you saw so that we get a better idea of what you want to achieve ?

Comment: Hey : http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/02/08/opencv-shape-detection/ it's one article I saw, it's detecting shapes and I need area basically :). Is saw some stuff like this too http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contour_features/py_contour_features.html

Thanks @Sunreef

Comment: This might be a good starting-point: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20706100/881500