# Hough Circle for Multiplicity Semi Circle

Tags: opencv, hough-transform

I have lots of curve But curves should completed to circle How can I do this process with hough circle I tried this method but I cant get a result
[Detect semi-circle in opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20698613/detect-semi-circle-in-opencv)
My image is here:

[image]

Comment: do you want to treat each of those segments as a semi-circle?!?

Comment: yes exactly @Micka

Comment: did you try the ransac version in the linked qurstion's answers? Maybe you have to tune the parameters a bit...

Comment: yes I did but I dont understant ,in the linked questions answer almost the same but hough doesnt work while ransac method is working Why hough doesnt work @Micka

Comment: opencv hough isnt so well for edge images, because (that's my theory) it internally computes the gradient again instead of using the edge pixels directly.
In addition, your edges don't look like real semi-circles, maybe hough has some hard coded maximum radius limitations and maybe your edges arent "circlish" enough.

Comment: hmm thank you I have to prepare a report about why hough circle is not work well (especially for  on my image),what is a base theory in hough ircle  for my project And I am looking for  a resource about this Have you another idea for this situation @Micka

Comment: in general, houghCircle function is quite sensitive to parameter changes. I would recommend you to try different hough circle implementations (maybe matlab?) too, maybe they are more robust.

Comment: Thank you can you give vote if you like my question @Micka

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123290/discussion-between-j-doe-and-micka).

Answer (score 1):

Hough circles is the only way to do this.

The image is noisy but I suspect the problem is that there are very few points and you are trying a wide range of radii. This means that the Hough probability for each circle is very low.

Do you know what the radii should be? If you do try a reduced radius range.

If not I would run the image with a set of small radii ranges and see which produce any result

Comment: Thank you for good answer :) but I dont know radii Can you explain radii or can you show me on the İmage

Comment: Radius is the half the width of the circle (radii is plural). With Hough circles you have to tell the function what range of radius to look for, if the rane it looks for is too big it won't find anything if the data is bad