# How to convert OpenCV Mat.at<float>(float,float) to EmguCV

Tags: emgucv

Sorry for this noob question. I am trying to convert code from this link [Detect semi-circle in opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20698613/detect-semi-circle-in-opencv) to C# but I am stuck in this line

*if(dt.at< float >(cY,cX) < maxInlierDist)*

I can't see equivalent of OpenCV *dt.at<>()* in Emgu.CV.
So I'd like to ask if anyone encounter this already and successfully write it in C# using Emgu CV.

Thanks in advance.