# Incomplete Circle detection with opencv python

Tags: python, opencv, geometry, detection

is it possible to get the coordinates of the incomplete circle? i am using opencv and python. so i can find the most of the circles.
But i have no clue how can i detect the incomplete cirlce in the picture.
I am looking for a simple way to solve it.

[image: captcha]

```py
import sys
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

## [load]
default_file = 'captcha2.png'
# Loads an image
src = cv.imread(cv.samples.findFile(default_file), cv.IMREAD_COLOR)
## [convert_to_gray]
# Convert it to gray
gray = cv.cvtColor(src, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
## [convert_to_gray]

## [reduce_noise]
# Reduce the noise to avoid false circle detection
gray = cv.medianBlur(gray, 3)
## [reduce_noise]

## [houghcircles]
#rows = gray.shape[0]
circles = cv.HoughCircles(gray, cv.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 5,
                          param1=1, param2=35,
                          minRadius=1, maxRadius=30)
## [houghcircles]

## [draw]
if circles is not None:
    circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
    for i in circles[0, :]:
        center = (i[0], i[1])
        # circle center
        cv.circle(src, center, 1, (0, 100, 100), 3)
        # circle outline
        radius = i[2]
        cv.circle(src, center, radius, (255, 0, 255), 3)
## [draw]

## [display]
cv.imshow("detected circles", src)
cv.waitKey(0)
## [display]
```

Hi - there is an other Picture. I want the x and y cords of the incomplete circle, light blue on the lower left.

[image]

Here the original Pic:

[image]

Comment: Can you also attach the current output ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the colorful background of your image and display only circles.

One approach is:

- Get [the binary mask](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d97/tutorial_threshold_inRange.html) of the input image
- Apply [Hough Circle](https://docs.opencv.org/master/da/d53/tutorial_py_houghcircles.html) to detect the circles

---

Binary mask:

[image]

Using the binary mask, we will detect the circles:

[image]

Code:

---

```py
# Load the libraries
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load the image
img = cv2.imread("r5lcN.png")

# Copy the input image
out = img.copy()

# Convert to the HSV color space
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# Get binary mask
msk = cv2.inRange(hsv, np.array([0, 0, 130]), np.array([179, 255, 255]))

# Detect circles in the image
crc = cv2.HoughCircles(msk, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 10, param1=50, param2=25, minRadius=0, maxRadius=0)

# Ensure circles were found
if crc is not None:

    # Convert the coordinates and radius of the circles to integers
    crc = np.round(crc[0, :]).astype("int")

    # For each (x, y) coordinates and radius of the circles
    for (x, y, r) in crc:

        # Draw the circle
        cv2.circle(out, (x, y), r, (0, 255, 0), 4)

        # Print coordinates
        print("x:{}, y:{}".format(x, y))

    # Display
    cv2.imshow("out", np.hstack([img, out]))
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

**Output:**

```
x:178, y:60
x:128, y:22
x:248, y:20
x:378, y:52
x:280, y:60
x:294, y:46
x:250, y:44
x:150, y:62
```

**Explanation**

We have three chance for finding the thresholding:

- 1. Simple Threshold result:

  - [image]
- 2. Adaptive Threshold

  - [image]
- 3. Binary mask

  - [image]

As we can see the third option gave us a suitable result. Of course, you could get the desired result with other options, but it might take a long time for finding the suitable parameters. Then we applied Hough circles, played with parameter values, and got the desired result.

**Update**

For the second uploaded image, you can detect the semi-circle by reducing the first and second parameters of the Hough circle.

```py
crc = cv2.HoughCircles(msk, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 10, param1=10, param2=15, minRadius=0, maxRadius=0)
```

Replacing the above line in the main code will result in:

[image]

Console result

```
x:238, y:38
x:56, y:30
x:44, y:62
x:208, y:26
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks, thats helps me to find all circles. i am looking for something like this you explained. I like the way with binary mask. But it is also possible to find the open circle on the lower left side?

Comment: *...Find the open circle....* you mean incomplete circles? I guess yes, but not sure without trying

Comment: oh yeah, i mean the incomplete circle. its just one open circle.

Comment: Which one? I thought I have detected all the circles in the input image

Comment: i added an other pic. there is an incomplete circle as well. i'm looking for the x and y cords.

Comment: Did you look at the [detect-semicircle-in-opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20698613/detect-semicircle-in-opencv)?

Comment: The rod-arrow on the image prevents from detection. Please upload the original image.

Comment: Hey, sorry 4 being away so long. I added the original pic. Yes Ahx i am looking for this. But this is C++ or? Is there a way with python?

Comment: I've updated my answer, please see the answer below **Update** part.