# How to detect semi-circular shape centers using opencv in python?

Tags: python, opencv, circular-dependency, hough-transform

I need to detect the most shared center among these semi-circular shapes:

[image]

I tried with the MATLAB implementation of the Hough Transform but whichever radius range I choose it does not find any center, so is there a way to find a solution using the openCV library?

EDIT: as someone requested what did I try, I tried the example here:
https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghcircles/py_houghcircles.html

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('opencv_logo.png',0)
img = cv2.medianBlur(img,5)
cimg = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,20,
                        param1=50,param2=30,minRadius=0,maxRadius=0)

circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
for i in circles[0,:]:
# draw the outer circle
cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)
# draw the center of the circle
cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)

cv2.imshow('detected circles',cimg)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

but applying this code to myimage, no center is detected.

Comment: those are no semi-circles. Where would you place the "centers" for that image?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Comment: @Micka the centers should be like the one in the answer of this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20698613/detect-semicircle-in-opencv

Comment: @Prune I've edited the question if you're still interested on that

Comment: Much better; I've retracted my down-vote and closure vote.

Comment: in the linked question there are shapes very close to circles. In your images there are no circles, it's more like ellipses.

Comment: And there are ways to extend the concept for ellipse-like shape as far as you know?