# cv2.HoughCircle is always giving none in Google Collab

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, hough-transform

From 3 hours i am trying :
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(image_test,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,50,
param1=50,param2=50,minRadius=0,maxRadius=0)

circles is not getting output however image_test(image after canny edge detection) has object that i see through cv2_imshow. But when i pass original image then it is showing .
help me .
so now due to this : circles = np.round(circles[0, :]).astype("int") is showing TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Don't use canny image for houghCircle input. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20698613/detect-semicircle-in-opencv/20706100#20706100

Comment: @Micka Thank You :)